# display div on failed login in html, using Umbraco amd MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4, umbraco

I have a div in which I want to display a login error message only when a failed login is attempted.
The call to do the login is

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult HandleLoginSubmit(LoginModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return CurrentUmbracoPage();
            }

            if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.Username, model.Password))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Username, createPersistentCookie: false);
                return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl ?? "/login");

            }
            else
            {

                ModelState.AddModelError(nameof(model.Username), "Incorrect UserName");
                ModelState.AddModelError(nameof(model.Password), "Incorrect password");
                return CurrentUmbracoPage();


            }
        }
```

and the div is

```
<div class="col-lg-10 alert alert-danger justify-content-around mt-2" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="alert-icon">
                    <i class="material-icons">error_outline</i>
                </div>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="material-icons">clear</i></span>
                </button>
                <b>Error Alert: </b>
            </div>
        </div>
```

What should I return from the call if the login is successful, and how do I reference it in the html?

Comment: you are using your model in view right?

Comment: yes that's right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your version of Umbraco is 7.x. With the following controller name and the method name, for example:

```cs
public class RecoverUserDataSurfaceController : SurfaceControllerBaseController
{ 
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SubmitEmailForPasswordReset(UserModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return CurrentUmbracoPage();
        }

        bool success = _recoverUnpwWorkflow.RecoverPasswordSubmitEmail(model);
        TempData.Add("Success", success);

        return RedirectToCurrentUmbracoPage();
    }
}
```

The html should be:

```html
<form method="post" id="form-lost-password">
@using(Html.BeginUmbracoForm<UmbracoApp.Controllers.RecoverUserDataSurfaceController>("SubmitEmailForPasswordReset"))
{
    <div class="text-field validate-email required">
        <label for="EmailAddress">Email Address</label>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.EmailAddress)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.EmailAddress, new { @placeholder = "name@domain.com" })
    </div>
    <div class="submit-field">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" title="Submit" class="btn-default" />
    </div>
}
</form>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Umbraco 8, but what you've posted is enough for me to get things sorted, thanks